# Get relative URL from absolute URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want to get the relative URL from an absolute URL in JavaScript using regex and the replace method.

I tried the following but it is not working:

```
var str="http://localhost/mypage.jsp";
document.write(str.replace("^[\w]*\/\/[\w]*$",""));
```

Comment: I want output as `/mypage.jsp` to provided `http://localhost/mypage.jsp`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If by "relative URL" you mean the part of the string after the first single `/`, then it's simple:

```
document.write(str.replace(/^(?:\/\/|[^/]+)*\//, ''));
```

This matches all the characters up to the first single `/` in the string and replaces them with the empty string.

In: `http://localhost/my/page.jsp` --> Out: `/my/page.jsp`

Comment: @Tim - it is not working as the way you said. Outs me the entire url :(

Comment: Hm, strange. Try `str.replace(/^(?:\/\/|[^\/]+)*\//, "");`, how about now?

Comment: @Tim - yeah, this works now. but a little more problem. I want the part after second single `/`, can you plz help me modifying this regex?

Comment: @Tim - hey Thanks Tim +1, I got it working using `str.replace(/[\w]*:\/\/[\w]*\/[\w]*/,"")`, but still waiting for solution the way you approached. :)

Comment: In your example (up in your question) there is only one single slash - what should happen then?

Comment: @Tim - ya, I accept your answer as per my question. But it didnt satisfy my actual requirement, so was waiting for your response on my comment, as I find your approach more promising. Would be thankful to you if you can plz let me know how can i accomplish to get part after second single `/`

Comment: For everything after the second single slash, use `/^(?:\/\/|[^\/]+)*\/[^\/]+\//`.

Answer (score 70):

A nice way to do this is to use the browser's native link-parsing capabilities, using an `a` element:

```
function getUrlParts(url) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;

    return {
        href: a.href,
        host: a.host,
        hostname: a.hostname,
        port: a.port,
        pathname: a.pathname,
        protocol: a.protocol,
        hash: a.hash,
        search: a.search
    };
}
```

You can then access the pathname with `getUrlParts(yourUrl).pathname`.

The properties are the same as for the [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object.

Comment: Pathname will not return `query` (`a.search`) and `hash`.
So better variant, as for me, is `var urlParts = getUrlParts(yourUrl); var absoluteUrl = urlParts.pathname + urlParts.search + urlParts.hash`.

Answer (score 31):

Below snippet returns the absolute URL of the page.

```
 var myURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host  + window.location.pathname;
```

If you need only the relative url just use below snippet

```
 var myURL=window.location.pathname;
```

Checkout [get relative URL using Javascript](https://fluentprogramming.com/get-absolute-url-using-javascript/) for more details and multiple ways to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: `location.pathname` is the obvious winner for getting the active url in relative form! But why not just use `location.href` for the absolute url?

Comment: how is this so far down when `window.location.pathname` is obviously the correct answer here???

Comment: This answer is incorrect; if the URL has a query or a hash, they will be omitted when they shouldn't.

Answer (score 21):

```js
const url = new URL('https://www.example.com/path/#anchor?query=value');
const rel = url.toString().substring(url.origin.length)

console.log(rel)
// Output: /path/#anchor?query=value
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and looks like the simplest answer.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use low-level stuff like regexp etc. These things have been solved by so many other people. Especially the edge cases.

Have a look at [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/), it should do the job: http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#relativeto

```
var uri = new URI("/relative/path");
// make path relative
var relUri = uri.relativeTo("/relative/sub/foo/sub/file"); // returns a new URI instance
// relUri == "../../../path"
```

Answer (score 1):

don't forget that `\` is an escape character in strings, so if you would like to write regex in strings, ensure you type `\` twice for every `\` you need. Example: `/\w/` → `"\\w"`

Answer (score 1):

## `URL.getRelativeURL`

There's an public-domain extension for the standard `URL` object called **`getRelativeURL`**.
It's got a few cool tweaks like **force reload**, you should check it out!

### [Try it live.](http://jsbin.com/nodolu/edit?console,output)       [View on Gist.](https://gist.github.com/m93a/2553dd45de35aa05d0233c6f9dc04bc2)

---

Example usage

```
//syntax: <URL to convert>.getRelativeURL(<relative to this URL>)

//link from Mypage to Google
a = new URL("https://google.com/search");
a.getRelativeURL("https://mypage.com")
== "//google.com/search";

//link from the current location.href
a.getRelativeURL();

//link from Olutsee to Polk
var from = new URL("http://usa.com/florida/baker/olutsee");
var to   = new URL("http://usa.com/florida/polk");
to.getRelativeURL(from) == "../../polk";
```

Comment: Note that you have to include the code in the Gist, and it modifies `URL.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find script on that here we have only one problem which is one manual work, we want to add split attribute ie, if your site link is: [Get relative URL from absolute URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263454/get-relative-url-from-absolute-url)

we want to url as below:
/questions/6263454/get-relative-url-from-absolute-url

so in below code we have to add .com instead of .net ie,
        var res = at.split(".net"); here we want to add as per our requirement now i need to seperate after .com so code will be "var res = at.split(".com");".

i think you guys got that point if you have still doubt let me know please
and to see changes in code by inspecting:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a").each(function(){
    var at= $(this).attr("href");
    var res = at.split(".net");
    var res1 = res[0];
    var res2 = res[1];
    alert(res2);
    $(this).attr("href",res2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/jquery2">Change color</a>
</div>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/jquery3">Change color</a>
</div>
```