# RegEx - Get All Characters After A Specific Character (#)

Tags: javascript, regex

With the string below, how can I write a regular expression to remove or separately save only the characters that appear after the `#` symbol.

```
var category = "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var category = "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work";
var hashval = category.replace(/^[^#]*#([\s\S]*)$/, '$1');
//=> work
```

**OR better using String#match:**

```
var hashval = category.match(/#([\s\S]*)$/)[1];
//=> work
```

Comment: Not all URLs seen in the browser are well-formed, and this will break if the input contains a newline.  Just use `[^#]*` instead of `.*?` or better yet, `indexOf`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Not sure how a URL can contain unencoded newline but I believe my 2nd String#match should work better.

Comment: as I said, "not all URLs seen in the browser are well-formed ..."  For example, `myLink.getAttribute('href')` is not normalized the same way `myLink.href` is.  Ditto URLs reflected from the backend, and extracted from query parameters or form inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The nice way is to let the browser do the heavy lifting.

```
var category = "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work",
    link = document.createElement('a'),
    hash;

link.href = category;

hash = link.hash;
```

This has your browser create an `a` element and set the the `href` property of that element to be `category`. The browser then parses the URL. The link's `hash` property is the bit after the `#` in the URL.

I answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263454/get-relative-url-from-absolute-url/6263559#6263559) some time ago, with a more worked-out version of this code.