# How to get all digits after certain character using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

> @eur99.def.mark.ocal:7342s/mweb/web-style.s.git#v4.2.0

How can I get only the following numbers 4,2,0.

Basically I need all numbers after the dash sign (#);

I've tried this(using look behind pattern), but unsuccessfully.

Regex expression:

**(?<=#)\d+**

Note: PLEASE, not JS built in string methods

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19774560/5638869

Comment: YES and YES, you can ignore the web string!

Comment: Why can't you use JS string methods? Be careful of the XY Problem: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: You can't extract an indefinite amount of groups with (JavaScript) regex, but if you only have three groups of digits you can use this regex: `/#\D*(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)/`, and the groups of digits will be in the first three matched groups (which can be extracted with [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match/))

Comment: Yes I see now. tnx for the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses to remember matches, you can access them in the resulting array (indexing from 1, the whole match is stored in 0)

```js
const str = '"web": "@eur99.def.mark.ocal:7342s/mweb/web-style.s.git#v4.22.514"'
const regExp = /#v([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/
const res = regExp.exec(str)

console.log(res[1], res[2], res[3]) // 4 22 514
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight-forward approach:

```js
var regex = /\d/g,
    str = '"web": "@eur99.def.mark.ocal:7342s/mweb/web-style.s.git#v4.2.0"',
    sl = str.substr(str.indexOf('#v')),   // the needed slice
    result = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(sl)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    result.push(m[0]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I need regex...

Answer (score 0):

you can use indexOf to get the index of #

```js
var str = "@eur99.def.mark.ocal:7342s/mweb/web-style.s.git#v4.2.0";
var num = str.substring(str.indexOf("#") + "#v".length);
```

Comment: No, just regex...