# Regex: How to capture second part of the url by regex and jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

so these is my url which I need to split into two part.

```
1) http://localhost:8800/gb/

2) http://localhost:8800/gb/About.aspx

3) http://localhost:8800/gb/product.aspx?id=1&vref=201

4) http://localhost:8800/gb/Contact.aspx
```

now tell me which regex I should use to split the above url.
the second part will hold the url after from country code

suppose this is my url `http://localhost:8800/gb/About.aspx`
so second part will be About.aspx

I got one regex `(https?:\/\/[^\/]+)\/(.*)` which split url into two part but I want to get after from country code. thanks

Comment: You can use; [`var arr = url.split(/\/[a-z]{2}\//);`](https://regex101.com/r/9DqfhR/1)

Comment: @anubhava yes your code works `   var url = 'http://localhost:8800/gb/About.aspx?id=2&vref=3';
   var arr = url.split(/\/[a-z]{2}\//);
   alert(arr[0]);
   alert(arr[1]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` on 2 digit country code with `/` on either side:

```js
var url = 'http://localhost:8800/gb/About.aspx?id=2&vref=3';
var arr = url.split(/\/[a-z]{2}\//);

console.log(arr[0]); //=> http://localhost:8800
console.log(arr[1]); //=> About.aspx?id=2&vref=3
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9DqfhR/1/)

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach would be `^(?:\/\/|[^\/]+)*\/[a-zA-Z]{2}\/`. This is simply based on [Get relative URL from absolute URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263454/get-relative-url-from-absolute-url) with the addition to allow for a 2 character country code.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/5fpRWX/1/

Comment: when i test your code then it did not work. see how i test it `   var url = 'http://localhost:8800/gb/About.aspx?id=2&vref=3';
   var arr = url.split(^(?:\/\/|[^\/]+)*\/\S{2}\/);
   alert(arr[0]);
   alert(arr[1]);`

Comment: @Thomas your javascript is wrong. It has to be `url.split(/^(?:\/\/|[^\/]+)*\/\S{2}\//); `

Comment: why you add `/` as first and last char when paste the regex in split() function ?

Comment: Because that is how you use regex in javascript.