# How do I shorten an <img> source in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Currently I am making a game, and I want to check if my **html element** `'document.getElementById("terminal").src'` is equal to `"sprites/terminal.png"`....
Because I use a live server via visual studio code, the `"document.getElementById("terminal").src"` is actually equal to `'http://127.0.0.1:5500/sprites/terminal.png'`. Is there a way to change this or at least shorten the `'.src'` to exclude `'http://127.0.0.1:5500'`, and just be `'sprites/terminal.png'`.
Thanks

Comment: You can use `split()` method to divide your string as you require and check the same with your desired string;

Comment: How about `document.getElementById("terminal").getAttribute("src")`?

Comment: @AbinThaha Thanks for the reply. I tried this and it worked! Thanks

Comment: @SebastianSimon yes i think this would definitely be the better option as its extremely easy to remember. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `src` property, you could also check the `src` attribute, which the browser does not rewrite to an absolute URL so it will be exactly as in the HTML source:

```js
if (document.getElementById("terminal").getAttribute('src') === 'sprites/terminal.png') {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the most certain result would be received by using `URL()` constructor:

```js
const { src = ''} = document.getElementById('terminal');
const path = new URL(src).pathname;

console.log(path);
```

```html
<img id='terminal' src='http://127.0.0.1:5500/sprites/terminal.png' alt='terminal' />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look on
[Get relative URL from absolute URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263454/get-relative-url-from-absolute-url)
For a general URL extraction.

in your case, you can also do the follow:

```
document.getElementById("terminal").src.replace(window.origin, '')
```

which will return the path without the origin, then you can assign it back to the src:

```
const terminalDOM = document.getElementById("terminal");
terminalDOM.src = terminalDOM.src.replace(window.origin, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `URL` class in JavaScript to get the `pathname`.

```js
const image_source = document.getElementById("terminal").src;
const url = new URL(image_source);
console.log(url.pathname); //Output: '/sprites/terminal.png'

// if you want to skip the first slash, you can use substring
console.log(url.pathname.substring(1)); //Output: 'sprites/terminal.png'
```